# Upload larger files(200MB) to dropbox

Tags: wcf, web-services, dropbox

I have a problem.

I have a WCF running. The idea is that the service will upload files(200MB) to a DropBox account.

I've tried SharpBox and DropNet. Everything works like a charm until I try to upload files.
That means that login to dropbox and create a folder works, but upload does not work...

This is what I have tried so far:

Code sharpBox way 1:

```
ICloudFileSystemEntry file = _storage.CreateFile(_folderEntry, Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload));

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {

Int32 length = 1024;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[length];

    using (Stream data = file.GetContentStream(FileAccess.Write))
    {

        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(data))
        {

            bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            // write the required bytes
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Code sharpBox way 2:

```
_storage.UploadFile(fileToUpload, _folderEntry);
```

Code DropNet way 3:

```
byte[] content = _client.GetFileContentFromFS(new FileInfo(fileToUpload)); 
_client.UploadFile(_dropBoxFolder, Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload), content);
```

In webconfig:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

and

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

/Göran

Comment: `Everything works like a charm until the upload of files starts.`?? What happens then?

Comment: @gorhal: you have to be more specific. This is like saying "The applicaton seems fine until I open Visual Studio to start programming"

Comment: Yes the thing is it works when logging in and creating a directory.
When using DropNet, it creates the file but the upload stops after 1MB.
And when using SharpBox no file is created...

Comment: Is it possible to use buffered stream

Comment: Yes or at least thats what I have been trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the max file length in your web config?

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. Yes I have done that. I can't get to my  code now. But later on today I will add some code...